# Define function with condition NA

Tags: r, function, dataframe, each

I have the following dataframe

```
date1         date2           Date3        n_var
2017-02-01    2019-02-04      2018-04-01   2
2016-02-01    NA              2017-01-02   3
2017-02-01    2019-02-04      2020-04-01   7
2016-02-01    2019-02-04      2020-04-01   7
```

And i want this

```
date1         date2           Date3        price 
2017-02-01    2019-02-04      2018-04-01   2
2016-02-01    NA              2017-01-02   3
2017-02-01    2019-02-04      2020-04-01   NA
2016-02-01    2019-02-04      2020-04-01   NA
```

Rules :

date3 < date1 we pute na in column n_var
date2 is na and date2 < date3 --> we put na in column n_var
otherwise we want the value at each row for n_var

This is my code :

```
f_NA <- function(nvar)
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        df$nvar[i,] <- ifelse((date3<date1), NA,
                                 ifelse(((!is.na(date2)) & date3>date2), NA,df$nvar[i,]))
                          }
```

but it does'nt walk?

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized so no need for a loop. Check if your `date[1:3]` variables are set `as.Date`, If not  convert them and try again

Comment: yes it's date! I have already converted it

Comment: Also you should probably use `df$nvar[i]` or `df[i,]` instead of `df$nvar[i,]`.

Comment: I am not sure if your rule is correct. If `date2` is `NA` then the second condition does not matter. The result will always be `NA` because the conditional statement `date2<date3` is then not possible.

Comment: I have the case in my dataframe

Comment: `column n_var date2 is na and ....`? Your code is doing opposite of what the rule is stated here for the second condition. May be it is a typo.

Comment: Is it your intention to change the column name from `n_var` to `price`?

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

f = function(DF, nvar) DF[!(date2 >= Date3 & Date3 >= date1), (nvar) := NA][]

f(DF, "n_var")
```

It works like `DF[filter, edit columns]`. You don't need to separately treat cases where `date2` is NA, since they will be skipped during filtering anyways.

Note that this function modifies the input table, rather than just returning a new one with the column edits.

Data

```
DF = structure(list(date1 = structure(c(17198, 16832, 17198, 16832
), class = "Date"), date2 = structure(c(17931, NA, 17931, 17931
), class = "Date"), Date3 = structure(c(17622, 17168, 18353, 
18353), class = "Date"), n_var = c(2L, 3L, 7L, 7L)), .Names = c("date1", 
"date2", "Date3", "n_var"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: it is not ok, i have the following error,  Error in `:=`((nvar), NA): impossible to find function ":="
Traceback:

Comment: why not just `DF[!(date2 >= Date3 & Date3 >= date1), nvar := NA]` ?

Comment: @Naï you need to also pass the lines above, and probably `install.packages("data.table")` prior to that. `:=` is from [tag:data.table]

Comment: @Naï Yeah, if the `library` command on the first line doesn't work, the rest won't either.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to try it. `ifelse` construct should have worked as well but not sure what is happening there.

```
date1 <- c("2017-02-01", "2016-02-01", "2017-02-01", "2016-02-01")       
date2 <- c("2019-02-04", NA, "2019-02-04", "2019-02-04")    
date3 <- c("2018-04-01", "2017-01-02", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-01")
n_var <- c(2,3,7,7)

df <- cbind.data.frame(date1,date2, date3, n_var)
df$date1 <- as.Date(df$date1, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df$date2 <- as.Date(df$date2, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df$date3 <- as.Date(df$date3, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

idx1 <- df$date3<df$date1
idx2 <- !is.na(df$date2) & df$date2<df$date3

df$n_var[c(idx1 | idx2)] <- NA
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The ifelse problems are that it is being used inside a loop unnecessarily and inside a function without returning the end result.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
f_NA <- function(nvar){
  condition1 <- which(df$date3 < df$date1)
  condition2 <- intersect(which(!is.na(df$date2)), which(df$date2 < df$date3))
  cc <- union(condition1, condition2)
  df$nvar[cc] <- NA
  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` works on vectors, so you don't need to use the [i,] index, or the loop for that matter. Instead, use directly:
(This code works for me, thanks Drj for building the data)

```
date1 <- c("2017-02-01", "2016-02-01", "2017-02-01", "2016-02-01")       
date2 <- c("2019-02-04", NA, "2019-02-04", "2019-02-04")    
date3 <- c("2018-04-01", "2017-01-02", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-01")
n_var <- c(2,3,7,7)
df <- cbind.data.frame(date1,date2, date3, n_var)
df$date1 <- as.Date(df$date1, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df$date2 <- as.Date(df$date2, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df$date3 <- as.Date(df$date3, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
f_NA <- ifelse(df$date3<df$date1, NA,
               ifelse(((!is.na(df$date2)) & df$date3>df$date2), NA,df$n_var))
```

Comment: I just slighly changed it, try again and give me the error message?

Comment: I don't have error, but I have a null value for f_NA, 'logical(0)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using `NA_character_` instead of `NA` in your function?